# C# - How to assign the result of GetFromJsonAsync to a variable, and use it without it repeatedly calling the GET request?

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, asynchronous, get

I am trying to assign a class property with the result of a GET request, such that all other methods in the class can use the value of that property without having to call the GET request more than once. Bottom line is I want to call the GET Request during class instantiaton, assign it to a variable, and then never call it again during the objects lifetime.

```
public class Example {
  
  private readonly HttpClient _http;
  private readonly List<Thing> _things;
  
  public Example(HttpClient http) 
  {
    _http = http;
    _things = _http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Thing>>("https://api-to-call/endpoint").Result;
  }

  public void UseThings()
  {
    // Do something with _things;
  }

}
```

However, when the method is called, it is sending a new GET request to retrieve an updated value of the property I assigned in the constructor. How can I code this so it only calls the GET request once during object instantiation?

Comment: You shouldn't make async calls in a constructor. Instead you should do that elsewhere in your program flow after the object has been constructed, such as by making the `UseThings` method `async` and doing it there.

Comment: Generally, and _assuming_ it's not volatile, you'd _cache_ it somewhere (expiring or not,  user/request specific or not, depending on your use case/data) and only if necessary, refresh it accordingly.

Comment: As you've probably figured out, you can't make a class constructor asynchronous. Without going down a rabbit hole on re-architecting your solution, what you could do is just store the `Task` itself as a class member, then in your methods await the result of it.

Comment: See this: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html

Comment: UseThings() does not execute a GET again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not block in the constructor and .Result can have nasty side-effects.  While there have been discussions of a language feature to support this, until then, you should move this out to a cached operation. You can ensure that the operation only runs once by wrapping the http call with a `SemaphoreSlim`.

```
public class Example
{
    private readonly HttpClient _http;
    private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _lock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
    private List<Thing> _things;

    public Example(HttpClient http)
    {
        _http = http;
    }

    public async Task UseThings()
    {
        // Do something with _things;
        var localThings = _things ?? await GetThingsAsync();
    }
    
    private async Task<List<Thing>> GetThingsAsync()
    {
        if (_things != null)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(_things);
        }
        
        await _lock.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            // double check in case another thread has completed
            if (_things != null)
            {
                return _things;
            }
            
            _things = await _http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Thing>>("https://api-to-call/endpoint");
            return _things;
        }
        finally 
        {
            _lock.Release();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think about making both properties static? i.e, "private static HttpClient _http = new()" and  "private static Task<List<Thing>> = _http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Thing>>("https://api-to-call/endpoint")". This works in preventing the additional trips to the endpoint with the least amount of code.

Comment: That will block and depending on the context, could deadlock.  In addition, since it is static, it could even block application spin-up if the object graph is created during initalization.